# error: @Subcomponent.Factory method has parameters for modules or subcomponents that aren't required

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

So i was build a dagger app and was trying get rid of subcomponent using
`@ContributesAndroidInjector`
But, its throwing `error: @Subcomponent.Factory method has parameters for modules or subcomponents that aren't required`, I tried everything and scorched whole internet but did not find any fix to that , So please look at my code and please do suggest me a fix.

ActivitiesModule:-

```
@Module 
abstract class ActivitiesModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector()
    abstract fun bind():MainActivity
}
```

ApplicationComponent:-

```
@Component(modules = [AndroidInjectionModule::class,ActivitiesModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent {

    fun inject(app:Application)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder{
        fun build():ApplicationComponent

        @BindsInstance
        fun applicationBind(app: Application):Builder
    }
}
```

, I did not add any module or anything , I just am trying to inject my activity using `@ContributesAndroidInjector` approach.

And below are the lib's i am using:-

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.28'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28'
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.28"
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.18'
```

Comment: I solved this issue by fixing the dependancy version of  'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.18'.